# Função attr jquery não funciona

Tags: jquery

Criei a função attr em jquery mas não esta pegando qual seria o motivo?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<script>

    $( "#teste" ).attr( "itemprop", "name" );

</script>

<div id="teste">
    aaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
```

Comment: Não fico claro qual é o resultado esperado.

Comment: Não ficou claro o que está tentando fazer @Josimara. O que seria pegando? Para obter o valor do atributo, o segundo argumento na função é desnecessário, e não existe a propriedade `itemprop` em `teste`.

Answer (score 2):

O elemento ainda não existe na ordem que você chamou, para checar se a página já foi completamente renderizada use `$.ready(function() {...})` ou simplesmente `$(function() {...})` (é um atalho para `.ready`)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<script>
$(function () {
    $( "#teste" ).attr( "itemprop", "name" );
});
</script>

<div id="teste">
    aaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
```

Como o elemento foi criado somente depois de executar a função o jQuery não tem como encontrar, um exemplo de teste:

Não funciona, retorna zero (0):

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<script>
console.log($( "#teste" ).length);
</script>

<div id="teste">
    aaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
```

Se você usar `onload` ou `DOMContentLoaded` (mais rápido) ou `$.ready` (equivale ao `DOMContentLoaded`) então eles irão colocar a função para esperar a página ser carregada, um teste, retorna um (1):

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<script>
$(function () {
   console.log($( "#teste" ).length);
});
</script>

<div id="teste">
    aaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
```